# In python 2.7, how can I compare lines with the number of items in a list?

Tags: python, loops, if-statement, python-2.7

I am trying to print line[4] if there are 4 items, or line [4] and [5] if there are more than 4 items.

```
def onlinedoc(test):
    for line in test:
        lines = line.split()
        if 'report' in lines:
            if lines > [4]:      #<---- this is where i need help
                doc = lines[4] + lines[5]
            else:
                doc = lines[4]
    return doc

if __name__ == '__main__':
    test = open('test_documentation.txt', 'r')
    print
    onlinedoc(test)
```

I'm not sure what I'm suppose to put where I have if lines > [4]. I always get `IndexError: list index out of range`. I have double-checked and the information I want will either be in [4] or [5]. If I copy the lines to a separate text and do it without the if else and just

```
if 'report' in lines:
    host = lines[4] + lines[5]
```

then it works (on a line with 5).

Comment: It's pretty unclear what you're trying to do. We have no idea what you mean by "a line with 4"

Comment: a line with 4 items or a line with 5 items  when split

Comment: Its not terribly unclear. The problem is that you are trying to execute a syntactically incorrect command. Take a look at the len() function and re-evaluate the condition in the if-expression that is giving you problems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use `if len(lines)> 4`

Answer (score 2):

Use `len`:

```
def onlinedoc(test):
    for line in test:
        lines = line.split()
        if 'report' in lines:
            if len(lines) > 4:
                doc = lines[4] + lines[5]
            else:
                doc = lines[4]
    return doc
```

You should read Python's [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#len) for Built-in Functions

Answer (score 1):

You can use len(lines) or try/except

```
if 'report' in lines:
    if len(lines) > 4:
        doc = lines[4] + lines[5]
    else:
        doc = lines[4]
```

or try/except

```
if 'report' in lines:
    try:
        doc = lines[4] + lines[5]
    except IndexError:
        doc = lines[4]
```

This assumes you always have at least four items !